# Count highest number of co-occurrences of a value in another column (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a table like this:

```
----------------
| ID | Author |
----------------
| 24 | Cathy  |
| 24 | NULL   |
| 24 | NULL   |
| 24 | Thomas |
| 70 | Cathy  |
| 70 | NULL   |
| 99 | Lisa   |
----------------
```

Imagine counting how often all of Cathy's `ID` co-occur with other `Authors`.

The result should be `4` co-authors (3x `NULL` + 1x `Thomas`).

Now I want to find out which `Author` (who `IS NOT NULL`) has the highest number of co-authors, which could result in something like this:

```
---------------------------------
| Author | Number of Co-Authors |
---------------------------------
| Cathy  |           4          |
| Thomas |           3          | 
| Lisa   |           0          |
---------------------------------
```

How is it possible in MySQL? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is there a reason that you accepted an answer that does not even run: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=df0801acd84b4f1871517a67624260e7?

Comment: @forpas Another problem will be `GROUP BY author`, which is ambiguous, but as the answer includes extra columns looks like a mind reading is involved here. And we will never know the reason.

Comment: @forpas, interesting that you point it out.  Yes, astentx is correct, in my actual case there are more columns, more "inner joins" etc., and adapting berihulel's solution to my case was the one that worked for me most easily (and yes, it did work - - strangely!).

Comment: @anpami It is interesting. Do you have a column paper_id in your table? I don't see it anywhere in your question. If you actually do have it, how did berihulel know about it? If not, how did you adapt that solution that contains imaginary columns?

Comment: @forpas, no, I do not have the column `paper_id` in my table. I don't know why berihulel inserted it (it seems to be deleted now?). It would be too complicated to explain the whole table, but the query I use, based on berihulel, now looks like this: `SELECT x.orcid, x.family, x.given, COUNT(DISTINCT(y.orcid)) total 
FROM aureg x 
LEFT JOIN aureg y 
ON y.orcid <> x.orcid 
AND y.doi = x.doi 
INNER JOIN preg
ON preg.doi = x.doi
WHERE x.orcid IS NOT NULL 
AND y.orcid IS NOT NULL
AND preg.date >= '2021-01-01' AND preg.date <= '2021-06-30'
GROUP BY orcid
ORDER BY total DESC`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a self join and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.Author, 
       SUM(t2.ID IS NOT NULL) Number_of_Co_Authors
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.ID = t1.ID AND (t2.Author <> t1.Author OR t2.Author IS NULL)
WHERE t1.Author IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t1.Author
ORDER BY Number_of_Co_Authors DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d11857315983983a6275438092d73a32).

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select author, sum(num_coauthors)
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by id) - 1 as num_coauthors
      from t
     ) t
where author is not null
group by author;
```

`count(*) - 1` is the number of coauthors on each id.  That is, it is the number of "other" rows.